# Can't connect to SQL Server machine from another server any more

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

My sql server is on a machine `198.135.X.XX1`

My dev server is on a machine `198.135.X.XX2`

I used to be able to connect from my dev server to my sql server machines, but not any more.

I am still able to connect from my local machine, but not from my dev.

On the left is my local machine and on the right is dev machine:
[image: local_dev]

1. I checked SQL browser and it is running;
2. I restarted SQL Browser just in case but it didn't help.
3. I restarted both machines, no luck.
4. Checked SQL Browser-> SSRPListener in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, but it's set to (1)
5. I checked firewall inbound rules and it has 1433 TCP port enabled for "Allow any"
6. I disabled all firewall on SQL Server machine just to test and still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From your `DEV` machine check using a port-scanner whether or not you can see `1433` of the SQL Server. Microsoft provides [PortQryUI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009) or the command-line alternative [`PortQry`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148)

- if it says `Listening` then the server is listening on the specified port
- If it says `Filtered` then it received a TCP acknowledgement packet with the Reset flag set which likely indicates a firewall or software issue
- if it says `Note Listening` that means it didn't receive a response at all